# HTML changes are not saved when a checkbox is set and the page is changed in React + Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-5

I have an array with several "question" elements, each of them with a structure similar to this:

```
<><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 1</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
```

In order to give each element a bit of keyed structure, I store each array element in a helper component. The HTML of the questions is simply stored in "element". Simple:

```
const ElementoPaginacion = ({element}) =>{
    return(
        element
    )
}
```

Since there can be many of these elements in this array, they are displayed with pagination. The displayed page is calculated (apparently correctly, using a simple calculation). The code snippet that calculates and displays it is as follows:

```
        <>
        {
            //Calculate init index (it depends ont the current page) to show the questions, and the number of elements to show (its rangePages)
            fullList.slice(currentPage * rangePages, (currentPage * rangePages) + rangePages).map((current) => (
                <React.Fragment key={current.key}>
                {current}
                </React.Fragment>
            ))
        }
```

What happens is that, when a change is made to that HTML by the user (for example, checking a checkbox), when changing the page, that change is NOT saved, if it is redrawed (for example, changing the page and returning to the same page afterwards). I am attaching images to see how it works:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

We can see how we make changes to the questions on page 0, we change to page 1, and when we return to page 0 again, the changes (check ckeckboxes) have not been saved.
That could be happening?

------------- EDIT -------------

Okay. Right now, the idea is to save changes to any portion of HTML that is passed to us, be it a question with checkbox responses, or a radiobutton.
The problem: if we don't know what content is going to pass, what we have to save is all the content in html. Now, how can we save any HTML content that has been modified? I've tried creating this helper component, which wraps the HTML content passed to it inside a "div", but when clicked, how can I retrieve the new HTML content to reassign (ie the "newData" parameter)?

```
const ElementoPaginacion = ({element}) =>{
    const [content, saveElement] = useState(element);

    const saveData = (newData) =>{
        saveElement(newData);
    }

    return(
        <div onChange={saveData}>
            {element}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a backend database? If not, the changes are stored in memory and will be lost each time you change the page.

You can use the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to prevent the state of the forms from being lost each time the element is dismounted. Then the user can submit the state in its entirety after answering the questions.

Example:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { Checkbox } from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  const [checkBoxIsMounted, setCheckBoxIsMounted] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCheckBoxIsMounted(!checkBoxIsMounted)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Mount Checkbox</Button>
      {checkBoxIsMounted && <Checkbox />}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Note, I'm using MUI instead of Bootstrap, but the underlying principle is the same.

The above code snippet produces the following behavior:

[image: A gif demonstrating that the state of a React component is not stored in memory when the component dismounts]

If we add state to the checkbox, React will maintain the state in memory even after the component is dismounted:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { Checkbox } from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  const [checkBoxIsMounted, setCheckBoxIsMounted] = useState(false);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCheckBoxIsMounted(!checkBoxIsMounted)
  }

  const handleChange = () => {
    setChecked(!checked)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Mount Checkbox</Button>
      {checkBoxIsMounted && <Checkbox onChange={handleChange} checked={checked} />}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This modified snippet produces this behavior:

[image: a gif demonstrating the checkbox behavior with react state]

Comment: Oh! So every time I change the page, the HTML is being reloaded without saving anything? It is that in the tutorials that I have seen, if something is changed in the DOM, it always remains saved, I do not understand why in this case, with pagination, it is different. At the end of the day, what I change is only what is seen, I do not modify the HTML (it is only modified when the user clicks and changes the checkboxes)

Comment: @Joe please see my edited post above for examples of maintaining state in React.

Comment: I'm trying to do a useStat with all the content, not just the state of the checkbox. My idea is that the Pagination class is used for elements with checkboxes, radiobuttons, and any other type of content that can be modified.

Comment: You can do that. Just set the state of the form instead of the individual checkbox. The code snippet above was just to demonstrate why you were losing your state.

Comment: I have added an "edit". I want to create that helper class capable of storing any type of content that is passed to it (HTML content). What happens is that it is not clear how I can get the new content, is there a way to pass all the content as a parameter in the onChange?